# Using Blockfrost api to get the price of an ada/token pair on Minswap

Tags: blockfrost, token

Can I use the Blockfrost API to query a pair that is on the Minswap DEX?

Comment: I am trying to use this adapter and the ts is not working in excell. I have installed the npm tho. It is not using the adapter so whats another way to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there should be a way to query a pair which is listed on Minswap via API.
I attached a github link to the adapter.

https://github.com/minswap/blockfrost-adapter

Comment: Thank you for your response, and the link to that repo as well.
I am trying to check from a web hook setup in blockfrost though - I receive a request from the blockfrost webhook and want to use the api there, on the server side to query the pair...the adapter you referenced assumes use of a client-side nuget/lib?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. To be honest, I just get started to start coding, so I can't really answer your quenstion for sure, but I assume it's a client-side lib.